# System context menu Icon not transparent like WinRAR

Tags: c++, winapi, icons, contextmenu, transparent

I added a icon at the system context menu(the popped up menu when we right mouse click on any file/foler). But the icon is not transparent(in xp its not notice able, but in vista/win7 it is clearly visible) there is a white background beneath the icon. But WinRAR or TortoiseSVN icons don't have any white background, they are transparent.

I tried the following C++ code:

```
#define BITMAP_MAIN 201 //in resource.h
BITMAP_MAIN BITMAP "main.bmp" // in .rc file

// showing icon in menu...
HBITMAP imgMain = LoadBitmap( aHinstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(BITMAP_MAIN) );
SetMenuItemBitmaps ( hSubmenu, uMenuIndex, MF_BYPOSITION, imgMain, imgMain);
```

[main.bmp is 16X16]

1. Also the icon(.bmp) is not shown fully in non-english OS.

So is there be any special technique to make the icon in the system context menu transparent like WinRAR?

Comment: As you can see int the SetMenuItemBitmaps function takes only HBITMAP type arguments. I tried loading .ico file and converted it to HBITMAP and then passed the icon to this function, but it didn't solve the problem.
By the way, I will pay attention accepting people's answers next time. Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 1):

You need a special mechanism for loading icons in Vista and later, since they don't seem to process (by default) transparencies in BMP files. You need to detect the operating system:

```
// Necessary for getting icons in the proper manner.
bool isVistaOrMore() {
  OSVERSIONINFOEX inf;
  SecureZeroMemory(&inf, sizeof(OSVERSIONINFOEX));
  inf.dwOSVersionInfoSize = sizeof(OSVERSIONINFOEX);
  WORD fullver = GetVersionEx((OSVERSIONINFO *)&inf);
  return (fullver >= 0x0600);
}
```

If it returns false then do what you're doing right now, if it returns true, perform something analog to what's described in:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb757020.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I think TortoiseSVN uses owner-draw menus.
Don't know about winrar, but this code might work even on win98 where TransparentBlt has memory leak.
Bitmap must have color table (8-bit).

Use like this (this code formatting can mangle text, so check for errors!)

```
//we replace magenta with menu color
ReplaceDIBColor(m_hMenuBmp, RGB(255,0,255), GetSysColor(COLOR_MENU));
```

//function
inline BOOL ReplaceDIBColor(HBITMAP &hDIB, COLORREF oldColor, COLORREF newColor)
{
    BOOL bRet=FALSE;
    //get color information
    DIBSECTION ds;
    if (!GetObject(hDIB, sizeof(DIBSECTION), &ds)) return FALSE;
    if (ds.dsBmih.biBitCount>8) return FALSE; //must be 8 bpp max

`HDC hDC=CreateCompatibleDC(NULL);
if (!hDC) return FALSE;
HBITMAP hbmpOld=(HBITMAP)::SelectObject(hDC, hDIB);

//allocate color table
UINT nColors = ds.dsBmih.biClrUsed ? ds.dsBmih.biClrUsed : 1<<ds.dsBmih.biBitCount; //bpp to UINT
RGBQUAD* ptbl=(RGBQUAD*)CoTaskMemAlloc(nColors*sizeof(RGBQUAD));
if (ptbl)
{
    if (GetDIBColorTable(hDC, 0, nColors, ptbl))
    {
        //replace color table entries
        UINT i;
        for (i=0; i<nColors ; i++)
        {
            if (oldColor==RGB(ptbl[i].rgbRed, ptbl[i].rgbGreen, ptbl[i].rgbBlue))
            {
                ptbl[i].rgbRed=GetRValue(newColor);
                ptbl[i].rgbGreen=GetGValue(newColor);
                ptbl[i].rgbBlue=GetBValue(newColor);
                bRet=TRUE;
            }
        }
        //set new table
        if (bRet)
            if (!SetDIBColorTable(hDC, 0, nColors, ptbl)) bRet=FALSE;
    }
    //cleanup
    CoTaskMemFree(ptbl);
    ptbl=NULL;
    bRet=TRUE;
}
else bRet=FALSE;

hDIB=(HBITMAP)::SelectObject(hDC, hbmpOld);
DeleteDC(hDC);  return bRet;  }`